# When custom class loader becomes gc root?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, classloader, jvm-hotspot

Quote from https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/gc_roots.jsp:

> There are several kinds of GC roots. One object can belong to more than one kind of root. The root kinds are:
>
> - (...)
> - Held by JVM - objects held from garbage collection by JVM for its purposes. Actually the list of such objects depends on JVM implementation. Possible known cases are: the system class loader, a few important exception classes which the JVM knows about, a few pre-allocated objects for exception handling, and **custom class loaders when they are in the process of loading classes**.

Under what circumstances my own class loader becomes gc root? How can I stop "*process of loading classes*"? What can I do if jvm (HotSpot) prevents my class loader from being gc-ed despite not having path to any other gc root?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that you should worry about this. When ordinary Java code is in the process of loading classes through your custom class loader, it would be natural that the class loader can’t get garbage collected while the process is ongoing. But in that case, a Java stack frame of the thread using the `ClassLoader` would be reported as the garbage collection root (at least, if no other roots exist).

Now, when the JVM does the same, e.g. when resolving dependencies, there isn’t necessarily a Java stack frame containing a variable pointing to the class loader, hence, it may report the class loader as being in use by the JVM without reporting one of the other categories, so “Held by JVM” is the category then.

Still, a JVM won’t be within the process of loading a class without a reason. Resolving a class through a particular class loader implies that the class loader would be reachable anyway, directly or indirectly, from the class whose symbols are to be resolved. Being reported as being referenced by a GC root doesn’t preclude being reachable through another chain of references as well. There is a theoretical possibility to encounter a class loader in the process of loading without other chains of references, though, if the reachability changes during the process. But that would be only an issue of the timing of the snapshot, not an indicator for a problem.

But keep in mind that there might be other reasons for getting “Held by JVM”, e.g. a JVM doesn’t need to support class unloading at all (for HotSpot, configurable via options). If class unloading is not supported, every class loader can be considered a gc root, whether being reported as such or not. But there is nothing you can do about this in that case.

Comment: "I don’t think that you should worry about this" - unfortunately my question isn't just for curiosity, it affects me: when I use wsdl2java gradle plugin there are troubles with unloading classes possibly causing OOM in metaspace. Long story short: classloader created at https://github.com/nilsmagnus/wsdl2java/blob/master/plugin/src/main/groovy/no/nils/wsdl2java/Wsdl2JavaTask.groovy#L97 is visible in YourKit as gc root and I don't know why. It has no other paths to roots visible in yjp, so I guess that's the only obstacle from gc-ing it and unloading classes.

Comment: You should have included that into your question. Discussing an actual issue is an entirely different thing than discussing a theoretical scenario. As said in yourkit’s help page and in my answer, there might be other reasons for being held by the JVM (rechecking that class unloading is enabled would be good). Mind that since Java 7, `URLClassLoader` has a `close()` method to free resources and prevent subsequent class loading attempts. If that doesn’t help, the only way I see, is to strip down the application until the issue disappears, then rebuild it, identifying what makes the difference…

Comment: "URLClassLoader has a close()", already tried that, doesn't help.